# My order total is "never assigned to", and will always have its value set to 0. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#

I am having a couple problems with my block of code. Everything is working how it should be but my total is always 0. The warning description at the bottom of my screen says as follows: " 'Order.Total' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0".

How do I fix this warning sign?

I am also receiving a warning saying that my `EqualsTo()` statement is being overriden but not `Object.GetHashCode()`. How do I fix these 2 minor errors?

I'll give the entire code if you want to put it into your IDE and try debugging it your self...I'll also just paste a portion of the code I think that is creating the issue for the final total always defaulting to 0.

ENTIRE CODE

```
using System;

namespace Order 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // creating the orders
            Order order1 = new Order(1, "Joe Bob", 2);
            Order order2 = new Order(3, "Sally Bob", 4);
            Order order3 = new Order(1, "Jimmy Bob", 5);
            Console.WriteLine(order1.ToString() + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine(order2.ToString() + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine(order3.ToString() + "\n");

            //checks for duplicates
            CheckDuplicate(order1, order2);
            CheckDuplicate(order2, order3);
            CheckDuplicate(order1, order3);
        }
        // output for duplicates
        public static void CheckDuplicate(Order firstOrder, Order secondOrder)
        {
            if (firstOrder.Equals(secondOrder))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The two orders are the same!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The two orders are not the same!");
            }
        }
    }

    class Order
    {
        // setting properties
        double itemPrice = 12.35;
        public int OrderNum { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public double Quantity;
        private readonly double Total;

        // total price
        public double GetTotal()
        {
            double Total = Quantity * itemPrice;
            return Total;
        }


        // equals to method
        public override bool Equals(Object o)
        {
            bool isEqual = true;
            if (this.GetType() != o.GetType())
                isEqual = false;
            else
            {
                Order temp = (Order)o;
                if (OrderNum == temp.OrderNum)
                    isEqual = true;
                else
                    isEqual = false;
            }
            return isEqual;
        }
        // default constructor
        public Order(int OrderNum, string CustomerName, double Quantity)
        {
            this.OrderNum = OrderNum;
            this.CustomerName = CustomerName;
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
        }
        // returns final output
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("Order Number       : " + OrderNum) + "\n" + ("Customer name      : " + CustomerName) + "\n" + ("Quantity Ordered   : " + Quantity) + "\n" + ("Totatl Price       : " + Total);
        }
    }
}
```

PORTION OF CODE FOR `WARNING`

```
class Order
    {
        // setting properties
        double itemPrice = 12.35;
        public int OrderNum { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public double Quantity;
        private readonly double Total;

        // total price
        public double GetTotal()
        {
            double Total = Quantity * itemPrice;
            return Total;
        }


        // equals to method
        public override bool Equals(Object o)
        {
            bool isEqual = true;
            if (this.GetType() != o.GetType())
                isEqual = false;
            else
            {
                Order temp = (Order)o;
                if (OrderNum == temp.OrderNum)
                    isEqual = true;
                else
                    isEqual = false;
            }
            return isEqual;
        }
        // default constructor
        public Order(int OrderNum, string CustomerName, double Quantity)
        {
            this.OrderNum = OrderNum;
            this.CustomerName = CustomerName;
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
        }
        // returns final output
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("Order Number       : " + OrderNum) + "\n" + ("Customer name      : " + CustomerName) + "\n" + ("Quantity Ordered   : " + Quantity) + "\n" + ("Totatl Price       : " + Total);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `private readonly double Total;` is never assigned a value.

Comment: Make total readonly property `public double Total => Quantity * itemPrice`

Comment: Don't override Equals for Order, but have a method `public bool IsSameAs(Order order) => OrderNum == order.OrderNum;`

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, nothing is calling GetTotal() to assign the value to Total.

If you don't want to call GetTotal, you can put that formula in the constructor and assign the Total value at that time.

Comment: That and `GetTotal()` doesn't assign a value to the field `Total`.

Comment: Ha - good catch.